Zoom con una ImageView en Android Studio
¿Alguien sabe cuál es la librería actualizada de Android Studio para hacer zoom a una imagen desde un ImageView para la version de Android 2023.1.2?
implementation ("com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.10.0")


Quieres solo saber cual es la version actual? recuerda que esto depende de la configuraciòn de tu proyecto
